# Using fetch (POST) calling a laravel API, the request object is empty

Tags: laravel, fetch

I'm having an issue where I am using fetch within a Vue app to call my Laravel API.
However, my request object in Laravel is empty

This is using fetch with laravel 6. I tried using postman and axios and both work fine.

```
const requestOptions = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: requestHeader(false),
          /* eslint-disable-next-line */
          body: JSON.stringify({ "email": 'test@test.com', "password": 'password' })
        }

        return fetch(`${baseUrl}/auth/authenticate`, requestOptions)
```

Laravel Controller:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request) : JsonResponse
    {
        return response()->json(['message' => $request], 422);
    }
```

The $request object is empty.

if I do this. then I see the data:

```
$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong with fetch. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
  "X-CSRF-TOKEN": "{{csrf_token()}}"
},
```

Comment: Welcome & thanks for contributing. Please edit to add an expansion as to why the choose you suggested solved the OP's issue. Code only responses are discouraged on SO. Quality answers receive upvotes over time, as future visitors learn something from your post that they can then apply to their own coding issues, or to prevent future issues.

Comment: Also, please take care to use pepper capitalisation, grammar, at all.